# Cannot configure SSL with nginx on windows server

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, windows-server

It's been two days that I've been trying to configure my website in https but nothing works.

Here is my configuration file :

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log  info;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       9998 ssl;
        server_name  mysubdomain.domain.fr;

        ssl_certificate      "C:/path_to_cert.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key  "C:/path_to_rsa.rsa";

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

On firefox I have PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR.

And with openssl -connect :
4384:error:0200274C:system library:connect:reason(1868):crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:110:
4384:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=0

Am I missing something? 
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are you sure that `.rsa` is the right file for the key? Also, Windows does the slash in the pathname backwards but I don't know if nginx figures that out on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I also tried with a .key and it's the same, moreover I don't have an error in the error.log for the access to the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of searching for the source of the problem, it turned out that it came from IIS installed on this computer and previously configured on this port which was blocking the connection.

Comment: Not much of an answer if you're not answering how to solve the problem. Please describe in detail how you solved it